# How do i get pinned item if user doesn't have internet connection

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I want to get my pinned items from local datastore if internet connection is not available but i got just empty list instead of items.

My pinned items are using `ACL`s so I don't know how to find items in background if I cannot use `ACL`s in offline mode. According to documentation:

*The only difference is that you won’t be able to access any data protected by Role based ACLs due to the fact that the Roles are stored on the server. To access this data protected by Role based ACLs, you may need to ignore ACLs when executing a Local Datastore query by calling the ignoreAcls method on the query. Note that after calling this, you cannot subsequently use the same query to load from the network.*

I can use `getInBackground()` but this function is used to get exact item with exact `objectId` from local datastore. It is not query.

This is my Parse API Call:

```
fun getItems(c: Context, itemState: Int, user: ParseUser, itemCallback: (List<ParseObject>, ParseException?) -> Unit){
            val q = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>(ITEM_REPORT)
            if (!isOnline(c)) {
                q.fromLocalDatastore()
                q.ignoreACLs()
            }

            q.whereEqualTo(ITEM_USR_ID, user.objectId)
            q.whereEqualTo(ITEM_STATE, itemState)
            q.include(POINTER_OBJECT)
            q.include(POINTER_OBJECT_ORGANIZATION)

            q.findInBackground { reportList, err ->
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(reportList)
                itemCallback(reportList, err)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe You forget to enable local datastore. Here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970861/parseobject-pinallinbackground-results-with-nullpointerexception

Comment: I had it enabled for a long time.